# iOS / iPhone engine, code or framework used for Comic Apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I recently noticed most Comic book apps I've downloaded seem to use the same reader code.

Walking Dead, Hetalia and [Do Androids dream...](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/do-androids-dream-electric/id369267162?mt=8) have the exact same behaviour and even the same messages.

Does anyone have any clue where can I find this shell. I'm guessing the company that builds it licenses this but I can't seem to find it with my searches. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology and will never find it as a "comic book reader engine" or so.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I know its very old post, but I got relevant task this week, and my searches dropped me here, 
have you found any way around to achieve Comics book like behavior ?
related link will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Plausible Labs. They've created the frameworks for Comic apps like Comixology. Should be what you are looking for.

Comment: would it required licensing for them ?